# I want to print the integer values same as specified in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
the_count = [001, 002, 003, 004, 005]
for number in the_count:
    print(number)
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My Expected Output is:

```
001
002
003
004
005
```

Comment: Try making it go up to 009 and see what happens. :)

Comment: >>> x = int(1)    
>>> NewStringVariable = str(x).zfill(3)    
>>> print NewStringVariable    
001

Answer (score 2):

```
print('{0:03d}'.format(number))
```

alternatively look at zfill or rjust

Comment: Form the query iam getting the values likePOList= 001,002,003,004,005,006                                                                           for PONumber in POList: logger.info(PONumber ) In log iam getting 0 in log

Comment: I'm not really that aware of pythons logging package, if it's not really necessary to keep the PONumber as an integer type I would go ahead and convert it to a string when you log it and do: for PONumber in POList: logger.info(str(PONumber).zfill(3))

Answer (score 2):

You should store numbers as string while defining bcoz as an integer 001 is same as 1  (for us) which is also what python stores accidentally. However in Python numbers with leading '0' means octal number(base 8). So it will work till 007.

```
>>> a = 001
>>> a
1
>>> a = '001'
>>> a
'001'
>>> the_count = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005']
>>> for i in the_count:
    print i
001
002
003
004
005
```

But once you pass the octal limit it will fail. Octal numbers go 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,etc.

```
>>> a = 008
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
the_count = [001, 002, 003, 004, 005]
for number in the_count:
    print(str(number).zfill(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it your intention to be specifying the integer values in the list on the first line in octal? Because that's what you're doing in Python 2 (in Python 3 the list values are `SyntaxError`s). Python 2 considers any multi-digit integer literal that starts with a `0` to be a numeric value given in octal format (See **octinteger** in the [Integer and long integer literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) section of the Python 2 documentation.)

If that's your goal, then you can format each value to printed as a 3 digit octal number with leading zeros like this:

```
the_count = [001, 002, 003, 004, 005]
for number in the_count:
    print(format(number, '03o'))
```

In Python 3 the rules for octal literals are a little different and the first line would have to be changed to:

```
the_count = [0o001, 0o002, 0o003, 0o004, 0o005]
```

Comment: Iam Getting the value from the query like 001,002,003 i want to convert into '001','002','003'

Comment: Is the value from the query a single string, like `"001,002,003"`? If not, what is it exactly? Hint: Try `print(repr(query))` to find out.

Comment: There are individual values getting from the query the_count=001,005,008,006,004

Comment: `the_count=001,005,008,006,004` is an invalid statement in Python 2 because `008` is a `SyntaxError` since `8` is not a valid octal digit. What does `print(repr(the_count))` display?